# Rails form_for wrong method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, form-for

I've got a weird issue with one of my forms. The form only changes one variable of the object, called admin_comment. It ends up in the show method of the controller, in the terminal:

`Processing by EnrolmentsController#show as`

Here is the `form_for`

```
<%= form_for enrolment, :url => enrolments_admin_comment_path(enrolment), method: :get, remote: true do |f| %>
```

And here is the rake routes

```
enrolments_admin_comment GET    /enrolments/admin_comment(.:format)              enrolments#admin_comment
```

And the routes.rb part

```
  get "enrolments/admin_comment"

  resources :courses do
      resources :enrolments
  end
```

When I delete the `method: :get` part from the form_for, it ends up at the update method.
Everything else with the enrolments controller/model works fine. Does somebody know what's going on here? Thanks!

**Update**
After nearly getting insane I've got it working like this, but only with :get as method.

`routes.rb`

```
  get "/enrolments/:id/admin_comment" => "enrolments#admin_comment", as: "enrolments_admin_comment"
```

`form_for`

```
<%= form_for enrolment, :url => enrolments_admin_comment_path(enrolment), method: :get, remote: true do |f| %>
```

If I change the method to :post, I get the following error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/enrolments/28/admin_comment"):
```

Two questions came up:
1. What do I have to change to make it work with :post?
2. As far as I understand, if I just would just state the controller and the verb (:get / :post / ...), rails would know which method it has to use as the verbs are mapped to the methods. But when I state the whole path (controller and method), shouldn't rails know everything it needs without the verb? The form params are being sent anyway.

**Update2**
Ok, I've changed

```
get "/enrolments/:id/admin_comment" => "enrolments#admin_comment", as: "enrolments_admin_comment"
```

to

```
post "/enrolments/:id/admin_comment" => "enrolments#admin_comment", as: "enrolments_admin_comment"
```

Now everything works fine.

Comment: Well, yeah, if you use `:get`, you'll invoke `#show`. This is how restful resources work. What's the question here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll be best looking at [Rails' Resource Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web)

---

**HTTP Verbs**

Each `resources :controller` you create in your routes.rb file creates a series of routes, which connect with relative HTTP Verbs:

[image: HTTP Verbs]

The `HTTP verbs` part of the routing system is the most important, as it governs which controller action is loaded. You can use the same path helper with different HTTP Verbs to route to completely different controller actions

If you want to create a new path, you'd need to set the HTTP verb to `method: :post`, like this:

```
<%= form_for enrolment, :url => enrolments_admin_comment_path(enrolment), method: :post, remote: true do |f| %>
```

---

**Routes**

Perhaps you'd be better with this routing structure:

```
  resources :courses do
      resources :enrolments do
          get :admin_comment, shallow: :true
      end
  end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had :post before but I think there was something wrong in my routing so it didn't worked at this time and I thought it was the verb.

Comment: No, I just testing, I'm getting a `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/enrolments/admin_comment.28"):` error.

Comment: I fogot, I've got a resources mapping concerning the enrolments, maybe this is the problem? I updated the question with this part.

Comment: Where does comments come into the routes? Does it have its own controller?

Comment: I wanted to use the enrolments controller and the admin_comment method in it to update the comment of the enrolment. The update method is already in use.

Comment: Okay, let me update my answer with some suggested routes for you!

Comment: Updated to include shallow nesting (it should work, but will likely require tweaking)

Comment: Ok, I updated my routes and now get an `undefined method `enrolments_admin_anmerkung_path' ` error but I think I've got the right direction now. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: No problem! If you need any more help, please let me know :)

Comment: Ok, I actually have two more questions :) Please see the update of the question.